# Compile (dependency?) error on Fedora

Tags: qt, x11, fedora

I've been working on a program called RoboJournal and I recently finished the 0.4.1 release. I'm currently in the process of packaging it for Fedora but for some reason the program won't compile on that OS. The exact same code builds fine on Windows and any Debian-based Linux (Debian itself, Ubuntu, Mint, et al). I had no problems packaging this for Debian.  Here's the the compiler output error message (running on Fedora 18 KDE version):

```
/usr/bin/ld: dblogin.o: undefined reference to symbol 'XkbGetIndicatorState'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'XkbGetIndicatorState' is defined in DSO /lib64/libX11.so.6 so try adding it to the linker command line
/lib64/libX11.so.6: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The problem seems to be that the Linker can't find whatever is supposed to control the XkbGetIndicatorState signal (one of the X11 libs).  This is used to determine whether caps lock is enabled while a certain dialog is active. Apparently, anything Debian-based includes this library out of the box while Fedora does not. I think this error is simply caused by a missing package but I'm not sure which one. Google gave me nothing useful. Any ideas?

Anyone who wants to test this for themselves can clone from git://github.com/pwizard2/robojournal.git. The app depends on the following packages (so far): qt, qt-assistant, qt-mysql, qt-devel, qt-webkit, qt-webkit-devel.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if the X11 runtime library isn't present on Fedora...  Shouldn't it be `/usr/lib64/libX11.so`?

Comment: Since the usrMerge feature went in `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64` are the same thing on Fedora - the first is a link to the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that you're not linking your program against `libX11` so you need to add `-lX11` to your link command and then everything will work.

The reason it works on some other linux distributions is that they allow symbols to be resolved using libraries that have only been pulled in indirectly - so if your program links against a library that is linked against `libX11` then you will be able to call routines in `libX11`.

Fedora has not allowed this indirect linking (by default) for several years now (see [UnderstandingDSOLinkChange](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/UnderstandingDSOLinkChange)) and several other distributions have also now followed suit.

Comment: I'm still having trouble making this work. I've added the -lX11 to the affected class in the makefile: "$(CXX) -c $(CXXFLAGS) $(INCPATH) -lX11 -o dblogin.o  ui/dblogin.cpp" but I still get this error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are adding the flag to a wrong place. The command with `-c` is for compilation, it ignores linker flags. You need to modify a command that produces the executable file/

Comment: I got this working by putting -lX11 in the header portion of the makefile. Thanks for the help.